# Better way to implement (in javascript) after,after_Last, before and before_Last string prototype methods

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I just implemented (in coffeescript) these javascript prototype methods but I got the feeling that there is a better way to implement them

```coffee
String::after                = (value         )-> if (@.indexOf(    value) == -1 or @.indexOf(    value) + value.size()     > @.size()) then '' else @.substring(@.indexOf(    value) + value.size())
String::after_Last           = (value         )-> if (@.lastIndexOf(value) == -1 or @.lastIndexOf(value) + value.size()     > @.size()) then '' else @.substring(@.lastIndexOf(value) + value.size())
String::before               = (value         )-> @.substring(0,@.indexOf(value))
String::before_Last          = (value         )-> @.substring(0,@.lastIndexOf(value))
```

Here are the tests I current have for these for methods:

```
it 'after',->
    value.after.assert_Is_Function()
    value.after('3'  ).assert_Is(''     )
    value.after('2'  ).assert_Is('3'    )
    value.after('123').assert_Is(''     )
    value.after('b'  ).assert_Is('c123' )
    value.after('bc1').assert_Is('23'   )
    value.after('xxx').assert_Is(''     )
    value.after(null ).assert_Is(''     )
    'abb'.after('b'  ).assert_Is('b'    )
    'a.b'.after('.'  ).assert_Is('b'    )
    'a.b.c'.after('.').assert_Is('b.c'  )


it 'after_Last',->
    value.after_Last.assert_Is_Function()
    value.after_Last('3'  ).assert_Is(''     )
    value.after_Last('2'  ).assert_Is('3'    )
    value.after_Last('123').assert_Is(''     )
    value.after_Last('b'  ).assert_Is('c123' )
    value.after_Last('bc1').assert_Is('23'   )
    value.after_Last('xxx').assert_Is(''     )
    value.after_Last(null ).assert_Is(''     )
    'abb'.after_Last('b'  ).assert_Is(''     )
    'a.b'.after_Last('.'  ).assert_Is('b'    )
    'a.b.c'.after_Last('.').assert_Is('c'    )

it 'before',->
    value.before.assert_Is_Function()
    value.before('3'  ).assert_Is('abc12')
    value.before('2'  ).assert_Is('abc1' )
    value.before('123').assert_Is('abc'  )
    value.before('b'  ).assert_Is('a'    )
    value.before('bc1').assert_Is('a'    )
    value.before('xxx').assert_Is(''     )
    value.before(null ).assert_Is(''     )
    'abb'.before('b'  ).assert_Is('a'    )
    'a.b'.before('.'  ).assert_Is('a'    )
    'a.b.c'.before('.').assert_Is('a'    )


it 'before_Last',->
    value.before_Last.assert_Is_Function()
    value.before_Last('3'  ).assert_Is('abc12')
    value.before_Last('2'  ).assert_Is('abc1' )
    value.before_Last('123').assert_Is('abc'  )
    value.before_Last('b'  ).assert_Is('a'    )
    value.before_Last('bc1').assert_Is('a'    )
    value.before_Last('xxx').assert_Is(''     )
    value.before_Last(null ).assert_Is(''     )
    'abb'.before_Last('b'  ).assert_Is('ab'   )
    'a.b'.before_Last('.'  ).assert_Is('a'    )
    'a.b.c'.before_Last('.').assert_Is('a.b'  )
```

I specifically don't like the **if** statements in the **after** and **after_Last** methods

I'm also wondering if I'm missing a couple test cases for the **before** and **before_Last** methods (since they are quite simple implementations :)  )

These methods are part of https://github.com/o2platform/fluentnode

Update 1: here is using version from **Patrick J. S.**

```
String::after                = (value         )-> if ((index = @.indexOf(    value)) == -1 ) then '' else @.substr(index + value.size())
String::after_Last           = (value         )-> if ((index = @.lastIndexOf(value)) == -1 ) then '' else @.substr(index + value.size())
```

I also added these extra tests for the '' case:

```
value.after_Last (''   ).assert_Is(''      )
value.after(''         ).assert_Is('abc123')
value.before(''        ).assert_Is(''      )
value.before_Last(''   ).assert_Is('abc123')
```

Comment: What should happen if you call these functions with `''`? And why aren't you checking if you overwrite some core function?

Comment: I just updated the answer to handle those cases, and yeah I need to figure out a mass/easy way to check for the overwrite scenarios in fluenode

Comment: Something like [this](https://gist.github.com/P-Seebauer/904b66d4ef9fca51d207#file-gistfile1-coffee)?

Comment: Also your new tests have the parens wrong. `value.after(      ''   ).assert_Is('abc123')`. Else you're testing if `''` is `'abc123'` and pass the result to `value.after`

Comment: oops, yeah the parens were wrong :) I just fixed it on the question, and just to double check, I just tried in on the real UnitTest execution and if there were those extra spaces, the test would fail with: AssertionError: "" == "abc123"

Comment: Thanks for the code sample for the overwrite issue. I added this issue to track it: https://github.com/o2platform/fluentnode/issues/10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here, is a little shorter, couldn't get rid of the `if` but the second condition can't happen anyway (I'm assuming you trust node's `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf`), so you can exclude it, also introduced a variable.

```
String::after                = (value         )-> if ((indx = @indexOf(    value)) == -1 ) then '' else @substr(indx + value.size())
String::after_Last           = (value         )-> if ((indx = @lastIndexOf(value)) == -1 ) then '' else @substr(indx + value.size())
```

Comment: You can also remove the dots `@.indexOf === @indexOf`

Comment: Thanks for the solution, lets see if shorter (or simpler) solutions appears, and if not, I'll mark this as the answer. 

Btw I like the version with the dots (it is also the convention that I used for the other methods: https://github.com/o2platform/fluentnode/blob/master/src/fluent-string.coffee )

Answer (score 2):

You always will need some kind of case distinction, because the `-1` return value of `indexOf` is rather unusable. However, with a bit of magic you can get around the if-statement:

```
String::after      = (value) -> @slice ~(    ~@indexOf(value) || ~@length) + value.length
String::afterLast  = (value) -> @slice ~(~@lastIndexOf(value) || ~@length) + value.length
String::before     = (value) -> @slice 0, ~(    ~@indexOf(value) || ~0)
String::beforeLast = (value) -> @slice 0, ~(~@lastIndexOf(value) || ~0)
```

Comment: Nice I had not used the ~ operator before and this is a nice use of it (if others are wondering how that works see http://dreaminginjavascript.wordpress.com/2008/07/04/28/ )

Comment: Once issue I have with this is that it does make it harder to read (i.e. ironically less simple than that Patricks's solution